# Installing the WCF data services

Tags: wcf, ado.net

I am trying to install the WCF data services from
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=79d7f6f8-d6e9-4b8c-8640-17f89452148e&displaylang=en

However, I only get the error message: "the update is not applicable to your computer".
I am using Windows 7 with .NET 3.5 SP1/.NET 4.0 installed.

Do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

This update requires .NET 3.5 **SP 1** - do you already have SP1 ?? If not - first get the .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1 and install that.

UPDATE: ok, so you do have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed - could the presence of .NET 4 cause your problems? Can you try on a second machine (or in a VM) with only .NET 3.5 SP1 installed?

Comment: I have .net 3.5 SP1 installed